# NPM request - Get TLS version

Tags: node.js, tls1.2

In node i'm using npm module "request" : https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

I want to know how i can retrieve from response the TLS version used, TLS1.0, TLS1.1, TLS1.2.

```
var request = require("request");

request.get({url: "https://www.google.com/"}, function(err, response, body) {

     console.log(response.req.connection._tlsOptions); // ??
     process.exit(0);

});
```

---

One of our provider will soon manage only TLS1.2 and i want to know which version is used now in order to know if i have to specify secureProtocol: "TLSv1_2_method" for this provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
require('request').get("https://www.google.com/").on('response',
  (response) =>
    console.log(response.socket.getProtocol())
  ); ""
```

`tlsSocket.getProtocol()` can not be used in callback as connection is closed by then, and TLS connection metadata is no longer available.

https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_class_tls_tlssocket

> Methods that return TLS connection metadata (e.g. tls.TLSSocket.getPeerCertificate() will only return data while the connection is open.

Answer (score 1):

You can send a request to howsmyssl.com

```
var allData = ''
require('request')({
    uri: 'https://howsmyssl.com/a/check'
}).on('data', function(data) {
    allData += data.toString()
}).on('end', function() {
    console.log(JSON.parse(allData).tls_version)
})
```

Comment: i want to know the TLS version used by  my provider "https://provider.com" not mine